# parallelize file processing (in loop)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to parallelize processing files.

I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool

SAVE_PATH = './tmp/saved/'
data_path = './tmp/data/'

def process_files(data_path):
    for idx_file, file in tqdm(enumerate(glob.glob(data_path + '*.txt'))):
        try:
            with open(file) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            # create a dataframe
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'title':lines})
            df.to_csv(SAVE_PATH + str(idx_file) + '.csv', index=False)
            
        except Exception as ex:
            print('\nError in file: {}\n'.format(file))
            continue
        
processes = []

for i, input_file in enumerate(data_path):
    input_path = data_path[i]
    process_files(input_path)
    process = Process(target=process_files, args=(input_path))
    processes.append(process)
    process.start()
    print('Waiting for the parallel process...')
    process.join()
```

but it processes the files many times.

I need to keep the loop in the `process_files` function.

So, I tried:

```
pool = Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(process_files, data_path)
pool.close()
```

but again, it processes the files multiple times.

So, after the comments, I can run the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool

SAVE_PATH = './tmp/saved/'
data_path = './tmp/data/'

def process_files(input_data):
    file, idx_file = input_data 
    try:
        with open(file) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'title':lines})
        df.to_csv(SAVE_PATH + str(idx_file) + '.csv', index=False)
        print('Finished\n')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('\nError in file: {}\n'.format(file))
        

file = [f for f in glob.glob(data_path + '*.txt')]
idx_file = [idx for idx in range(len(file))]

input_data = zip(file, idx_file)

workers = 4
pool = Pool(processes=workers)
pool.map(process_files, input_data)
pool.close()
```

but, to extend further in my case, when I try to append to `USER_ID` list:

```
USER_ID = []
def process_files(input_data):
    file, idx_file = input_data 
    try:
        with open(file) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

        USER_ID.append(idx_file)
        print(USER_ID[idx_file])
        # create a dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'title':lines})
        df.to_csv(SAVE_PATH + str(idx_file) + '.csv', index=False)
        print('Finished\n')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('\nError in file: {}\n'.format(file))
```

I am receiving `error in file`.

Comment: I think you might want to `glob.glob` outside the function and then pass the paths to the pool

Comment: Why do you *need to keep the loop in the process_files function.*?

Comment: @Daviid: I want to keep the indexes `idx_file` and `file` in order to use them many times.

Comment: Then add that as arguments to the `process_files` function.

Comment: Also, you have `process_files(input_path)` and then `process = Process(target=process_files, args=(input_path))`

Comment: I think you've omitted something about `data_path`, as `for i, input_file in enumerate('./tmp/data/'): input_path = data_path[i];` doesn't make sense... it would loop over the characters in the string, then fail with an index error as soon as `i` was greater than 0.

Comment: if you are seeing "error in file", it's not coming from multiprocessing, and rather it's an error you are purposely ignoring with your `except Exception:` line

Comment: I solved your problem with progress bar and USER_ID list. Please see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this closer to what you're looking for? **Edit: removed tqdm which does not have good multiprocessing compatibility, and simplified example with glob.**

```py
from time import sleep
import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool

data_path = r'C:\Users\username\python\311\Lib\multiprocessing'

def process_file(idx_file, file):
    print(f"{idx_file}, {file}")
    sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.starmap(process_file, enumerate(glob.glob(data_path+r"\*.py")))
        pool.close() #close and join not strictly needed here, but good practice.
        pool.join() #leaving the `with Pool()` block with outstanding async tasks
                    #will terminate the pool before the work is done.
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but it gives me some errors. Maybe because you have `idx_file` and `file` in function args but when calling `starmap` you have one arg? I updated my post ! I run the code but I have another problem.

Comment: my bad... not really familiar with `tqdm`. it produces an incompatible iterator for starmap.

Comment: Ok it works now but I can't make the `USER_ID` list to be filled.

Comment: @George appending to a global list in an child process will not modify the copy of that list in the parent process. they are two separate lists.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do what you need. And since the accepted answer does not resolve the issue with `USER_ID`, I provide a solution to this problem + as a bonus with a progress bar as you originally wanted. The small [parallelbar](https://github.com/dubovikmaster/parallelbar) library will help us with this. It implements extensions of the `map/imap/starmap/imap_unordered` methods of the `multiprocessing.Pool` class that allow you to run parallelism with a progress bar, exception handling, timeouts for task execution.
Here is an example solution to your problem based on the accepted answer:

```py
#pip install parallelbar
from parallelbar import progress_starmap
import multiprocessing as mp

def initialize_process(x):
    global USER_ID
    USER_ID = x

def process_file(idx_file, file):
    print(f"{idx_file}, {file}")
    sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_id = mp.Manager().list()
    result = progress_starmap(process_file, 
                              enumerate(range(15)), 
                              initializer=initialize_process, 
                              initargs=(user_id,), 
                              total=15
                             )
    print(f'List with file idx is: {user_id}')
```

Out:
[image]

```
List with file idx is: [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 9, 7, 8, 6, 10, 11, 14, 12, 13]
```